# orgCharts html tags in tooltip

Tags: google-visualization

Look at this example
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart

I would like to know how can I add line breaks or html tags in the tooltips column.
Something like this (not working):

```
['Alice', 'Mike', 'Text1 &lt;br text2 '],
```

or

```
['Alice', 'Mike', 'Text1 <br> text2 '],
```

Column 2 - [optional] Tool-tip text to show, when a user hovers over this node.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tooltip from:

```
    ['Bob', 'Jim', 'Bob Sponge'],
```

is coded as:

```
    <td colspan="6" class="google-visualization-orgchart-node google-visualization-orgchart-node-medium" 
        title="Bob Sponge">Bob</td>
```

so option `allowHtml:true` wouldn't help. Tooltip is just plain html title attribute. So you can use unicode for line feed:

```
    ['Bob', 'Jim', 'Bob\u000ASponge'],
```

Comment: @Anto can I change the background color of the tooltips in google org chart?